# Why can't matlab print eps with certain shapes?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, eps

I recently "upgraded" from MATLAB R2011 to R2017b. Now when I try to print eps figures with relatively complex `fill` objects, they are rasterized.

This figure (and others like it) are OK:

[image]

This figure (and others like it) get rasterized (and larger, undesired margins):

[image]

The difference (from other examples) seems to be the sigmoid-shaped `fill` object in the bottom figure, versus the top figure, which has only c-shaped objects.

I know this may be related to well-known vector printing issues in matlab, and I have browsed the matlab help forums for solutions without success. What surprises me here is the subtle difference between the figures apparently causing problems.

Questions: Any known work-arounds? What do you think of my theory about the complexity of the `fill` objects?

Comment: Please post code for a minimal working example so that others can attempt to replicate your issue and look for solutions. Also please describe exactly how you are exporting to EPS and what OS you use.